# Why would a double completely scramble my stacked bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart using a numeric value stored as a double as the X-axis and a count of matching records as the Y-axis. I also want to show a categorical value. It works fine if my numeric value is an integer.

The simplest version I could come up with is a chart that uses the starwars library to give me a chart of the heights of various characters broken out by gender. It works fine. This code:

```
starwars %>%
  count(height, gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = n, fill = gender)) + geom_col()
```

Renders this chart:
[image]

And just to make sure I'm seeing what I expect, I can check the ranges:

```
starwars %>%
  count(height, gender) %>%
  summarise(tall = max(height, na.rm = TRUE), 
            short = min(height, na.rm = TRUE), 
            most = max(n), 
            least = min(n))
```

I have no idea what unit the "heights" value uses, but the tallest character is 264 units and Yoda is 66 units. The most frequent height appears 7 times. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to pull out those checks, but I'm able to confirm that the chart is consistent with the numbers.

My real data uses a numeric value stored as a double, rather than an integer, for the x axis value, and it came out looking bonkers. So if I repeat the chart above using a double from the Starwars data (birth year), I get mayhem. I can't even quite tell what is going on. The exact same code, with a different X axis value:

```
starwars %>%
  count(birth_year, gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = birth_year, y = n, fill = gender)) + geom_col()
```

yields a chart that is rotated 90° and makes no sense:

[image]

The "birth year" values range from 8 to 896, the most frequent year has 2 characters (31 give N/A for the birth year).

The only difference between the two charts is that the birth year is stored as a double. Why would that make the chart go crazy and (more to the point) how do I fix it so I can see the actual range of birth years on the x-axis and a bar showing the number of characters born that year, grouped by gender, on the y-axis?

Comment: I'm not sure that is related to double vs int, but rather to do with NAs. Add in `tidyr::drop_na()` before your `ggplot` call and you'll get a proper barplot. Not sure if your data has that issue, though; if not, can you provide a reproducible sample of it?

Comment: Depending on how your use relates to the example, either `geom_bar()` or `geom_histogram()` might be a more natural way to plot the data, removing the need for the `count()` function.

Comment: @heds1 I'm not sure where you're saying `tidyr::dropna()` needs to sit, but the problem is reproducible in the built in `starwars` data set.

Comment: @Miff I also need to illustrate a categorical value, and with `geom_bar()` the categorical values were getting placed one in front of another.

Comment: @Amanda `starwars %>% count(birth_year, gender) %>% tidyr::drop_na() %>% ggplot(...)`. I only mentioned your actual data in case that doesn't fix the issue :)

Comment: @heds1 if I can get the Starwars data working and mine is still busted, I'll explore anonymizing my own data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is intentional behaviour built into `ggplot2`.

Remember that using a `geom_col`, as in the first image, implies that you are plotting discrete elements on the x axis, with counts on the y axis. Of course, integers and factors can naturally be thought of as being discrete entities. On the other hand, doubles are normally used to represent an approximation of a real number, so we tend not to use them to represent discrete entities.

In the second plot, your x variable is a vector of doubles and your y axis is a vector of integers (counts). Because of this, `ggplot` assumes that the natural way to plot this is to have the categorical (or at least discrete) y axis as the binning variable, and the x axis as the continuous variable.

This behaviour is documented in the help file for `geom_col`:

> **orientation**: The orientation of the layer. The default (NA) automatically determines the orientation from the aesthetic mapping. In the rare event that this fails it can be given explicitly by setting orientation to either "x" or "y". See the Orientation section for more detail

So the "correct" way to fix this issue is to do:

```r
starwars %>%
  count(birth_year, gender) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = birth_year, y = n, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_col(orientation = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: This is a helpful explanation but I'm confused by the fact that your plot doesn't match the built in [Starwars data](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/man/starwars.html) where the genders are "female" (not "feminine") and "male" (not "masculine") and you've apparently filtered out None and Hermaphrodite categories. When I run your code I do see those values but I can immediately tell that I'm missing at least Yoda, who should show up as a male, born in 896. I don't see him on your chart either.

Comment: I added `width = 5` to the `geom_col()` attributes which brought Yoda out of hiding.

Comment: The genders in the dataset have been changed as of December 2019, [(GitHub log)](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/4480) so this is just a version issue depending on what version of dplyr is installed.